# NHibernate.Search Index Rebuild

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

How can i rebuild Lucene.NET Index using NHibernate.Search ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Index method off of the IFullTextSearchSession that will force and index of an entity. So you just need to retrieve all of the objects and then call index on them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
    public void Index(List<object> entities, ISession s)
    {
        using (var search = NHibernate.Search.Search.CreateFullTextSession(s))
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                using (var tx = s.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    search.Index(entity);
                    tx.Commit();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I would just build an index at a separate location and then delete and copy over the existing indexes to minimize the "downtime".

Comment: I found `search.PurgeAll(type)` suits my needs as well :-)