# Easiest way to reindex lucene.net indexes when nhibernate.search used?

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

Context =>
Calling wcf, some random stored procedures and sql stuff theoretically imports some data.

Requirements =>
Reindex lucene indexes for some of imported entities.

Question =>
What's the easiest way to do that?

Theoretically, if nhibernate is initialized, nhibernate.search should be aware which entities are supposed to be indexed. Therefore - i was wondering, are there any ready to use tools/whatnot to fulfill my requirement?

---

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111117/nhibernate-search-index-rebuild) the only way?

Comment: I used that way and it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My quick and dirty approach =>

```
 public static class LuceneReindexer
    {
        public static void Run()
        {    
            var entityTypes = typeof(FooEntity).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(Entity)
                    || x.BaseType == typeof(KeyedEntity));

            foreach (var t in entityTypes)
                if (TypeDescriptor
                   .GetAttributes(t)[typeof(IndexedAttribute)] != null)
                      ReindexEntity(t);
        }

        private static void ReindexEntity(Type t)
        {
            var stop = false;
            var index = 0;
            const int pageSize = 500;

            do
            {
                var list = NHibernateSession.Current.CreateCriteria(t)
                    .SetFirstResult(index)
                    .SetMaxResults(pageSize).List();

                NHibernateSession.Current.Transaction.Begin();
                foreach (var itm in list)
                    NHibernateSession.Current.Index(itm);
                NHibernateSession.Current.Transaction.Commit();

                index += pageSize;
                if (list.Count < pageSize) stop = true;
            } while (!stop);
        }
    }
```

No ideas about transaction and paging part (and don't care at the moment). Kind a does what i needed. :D